# how to make the node-exporter and cadvisor available to prometheus container only?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, devops, prometheus, docker-container

I have successfully setup Prometheus service in a docker container.Also I am running the services like node-exporter and cadvisor on different other ports in the same hosts.

All  the services are being run using the docker-compose.
Here is the sample

```
version: '2'


volumes:
    grafana_data: {}

services:

    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alertmanager/alert.rules
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'

    node-exporter:
        image: prom/node-exporter
        ports:
            - '9100:9100'
    cadvisor:
        image: google/cadvisor:latest 
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - /:/rootfs:ro
            - /var/run:/var/run:rw
            - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
            - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
            - /cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
        ports:
            - '8080:8080'
```

> How to make the **cadvisor** service not accessible to public as for
>   now everyone can access the cadvisor and node-exporter visiting the
>   host url with ports it is being assigned. But as the prometheus
>   depends on it only prometheus should be able to access it.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need to access the service externally, simply don't publish the ports for that service, delete the ports section from each of those services. The resulting compose file will look like:

```
version: '2'
volumes:
    grafana_data: {}
services:
    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alertmanager/alert.rules
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'

    node-exporter:
        image: prom/node-exporter
        # removed "ports" from here

    cadvisor:
        image: google/cadvisor:latest 
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - /:/rootfs:ro
            - /var/run:/var/run:rw
            - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
            - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
            - /cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
        # removed "ports" from here
```

Containers talk to each other across a shared network, which you get by default with docker compose or a docker stack. To use container to container networking, reference the target container by it's service name (in this case: `node-exporter` and `cadvisor`), and use the container port, not the published port, which in your case was the same.

Comment: Yes and in addition we can make it more secure by defining own network in docker and attaching that network to only required containers.

[docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/)

Answer (score 0):

This configuration should work as intended. Please note that you'll need to update your Prometheus config to reference the Node Exporter and CAdvisor by their alias names (`node-exporter`, `cadvisor`) instead of their IP.

```
version: '2'
volumes:
    grafana_data: {}
services:
    prometheus:
        image: prom/prometheus
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
            - ./alertmanager/alert.rules:/alertmanager/alert.rules
        command:
            - '--config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml'
        ports:
            - '9090:9090'
        links:
            - 'node-exporter'
            - 'cadvisor'
    node-exporter:
        image: prom/node-exporter
    cadvisor:
        image: google/cadvisor:latest 
        privileged: true
        volumes:
            - /:/rootfs:ro
            - /var/run:/var/run:rw
            - /var/lib/docker/:/var/lib/docker:ro
            - /dev/disk/:/dev/disk:ro
            - /cgroup:/sys/fs/cgroup:ro
```

Comment: Thats how I am running a node-exporter by not using the expose or  ports command . But when checking the docker ps it is still exposing the ports to the hosts. May be it is using the cache because i once used that port , will that case happen